# WebClient.DownloadData() returns Json with html tags like <pre> from WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, webclient

I'm trying to read from our production api which always outputs the json surrounded by <pre> tags 
The problem I am facing that when i use WebClient.DownloadData() it don't scrape the json only but also the <pre> tags which is unwanted 
I managed to come up with an api that outputs the json in <pre> tags when i try to read from it actually scrape only the json
Here is the working api https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/pikachu/ 
I tried to copy the formatting in the production api but no use

```
String Json = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[])(new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/pikachu/")));
Console.WriteLine(Json);
Json = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[])(new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData("remote-api-url")));
Console.WriteLine(Json);
```

Why the <pre> tags does appear in the first print only and the sources of the two documents has those <pre> tags

### Update:

It turned out that i use **ContentResult** to return put my json along with <pre> tags on the page so when i use this approach i get to output json with using the Formmatting.Indented .. Here is the code

```
return Content("<pre style =\"word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;\">" +new Response() { Status = "Success", Payload = null }.ToJsonString(Formatting.Indented)+ "</pre>");
```

thanks to [rene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene)'s remark about the page source, I knew the following: with using **ContentResult** the source of the page is generated as a full html document unlike **JsonResult** which will output the source containing the json only and it will generate the <pre> tags automatically here is the code

```
return Json(new Response() { Status = "Success", Payload = null },JsonBehaviour.AllowGet);
```

What if i wanted to have my json indented ? then the **ContentResult** approach should be used in the API along with [David's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60801569/9098126) to get rid of the  <pre> tags in the agent. 
**<<given that the server has properly escaped the inner xml content if there is any>>**

Comment: That url returns raw json.  No html at all, which you can see by running `curl https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/pikachu/ `

Comment: Do a `view-source:https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/pikachu/` and a `view-source:https://www.api.menaresearchgate.tk/`  and compare. The .tk server is adding that tag for some reason, ask the maintainer of that server why they wrap their stuff in a pre tag. There is nothing in your code that is causing that behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just treat the response as XML and extract the value of the root node.

eg

```
            var xml = @"
<pre style =""word - wrap: break-word; white - space:
pre - wrap; "">{""Status"":""Success"",""Payload"":null}</pre>";

            var json = XDocument.Parse(xml).Root.Value;
```

Comment: This will undoubtedly work and any <pre> in input won't affect the parsing but this not what i want to know refer to the latest edit in the question

Comment: this is also a bit brittle if there happens to be xml content included  in the json string.

Comment: Yes.  If the content isn't valid XML, then you'd need a custom paring implementation.

Comment: Yep.  The server properly escaped the body of the <Pre> node `"Payload": "&lt;xml&gt;content&lt;/xml&gt;"`